# How to retrieve changes of an expired model using REST / Django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

Imagine I have a REST backend and a mobile device which retrieves data from the backend. Is there any possibility to send a request from the device and get the changes of the model only? For example the device received and parsed the following model:

```
{ 
  id = 40, 
  vote_up_counter = 5, 
  message = 'This is awesome!', 
  author = 'Peter Morgan' 
}
```

Now someone else voted for this message and the model changes to:

```
{ 
  id = 40, 
  vote_up_counter = 6, 
  message = 'This is awesome!', 
  author = 'Peter Morgan' 
}
```

What I would like to have is a response similar to the folling, because I don't need to retrieve the message and author again :

```
{
  id = 40, 
  vote_up_counter = 6
}
```

Is there any way I could implement this? E.g. my mobile devices stores the model with a timestamp and if it has been expired, I request the changes / get an update of the model. I guess I would need to add a `last_modified` timestamp to my model or use something similar to version control systems.

I know this comes pretty close to push services, but I'm interessted if it's possible to retrieve the model update (using lower traffic) when pulling a request to the server. I would appreciate any help!

Best regards,

Michael

**EDIT :**

I need to mention, that I would like to send a request and update multiple objects. If I retrieve the objects with id 1 to 50 and only the object with id 40 and 42 have changed, then I would like to get a response of object 40 and 42 only, instead of all the other objects.

Comment: Is this something more than filtering the columns returned by your backend?

Comment: Yes I think so. Imagine the device retrieves a version from 10:00am (with 5 votes) and the model changes at 10:30am (to 6 votes). How would I send a request to the server to get the model changes from 10am to 10:30am?? One way would be to retrieve the whole model, but I'm interessted in retrieving the "change-model" (the third code example). And in this case the message and author will never change again, its only the vote_up_counter. Guess I would have to create a new view for this, right?

Comment: The question is do you want to retrieve only the changed columns, or all the objects that have been changed within that time slot?

Comment: The combination of both: One response should contain all changed objects since that timeslot, each of it with its changed columns. Sorry I did not clarify it in my post. The answer of hellsgate solved my problem. Thanks for taking your time! I really appreciate it! Have great day ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches here:

1. Add more fields to the model. These would be last_updated and fields_updated. There purpose is explained by their name hopefully.
2. Use [django-audit-log](https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log). You would then query the audit log table to find which fields had been updated since the last check.

In either case you'll need to add a model to track when a user has accessed a row in a table.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! I'll try to go with the second approach first :) But I think your first approach would also fit for my problem.